# Get Spring ApplicationContext OR Properties in Non-managed class

Tags: java, spring

I have a custom repository implementation (`MyCustomRepository`). This is instantiated by Spring from a `@Configuration` class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "xxx",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "xxx",
    repositoryBaseClass = MyCustomRepository.class,
    transactionManagerRef = "xxx")
```

This part all works ... but `MyCustomRepository` needs to get a `@ConfigurationProperties` bean.

The issue is that `MyCustomRepository` MUST have a specific constructor signature and Spring doesn't support `@Autowired` here either.

I would like to make the solution "application agnostic" so I can reuse it in multiple apps. The only solution I've found so far is to make the Application class implement `ApplicationContextAware` and then set it to a static variable somewhere.

I also can't use a `@Component` because initialization order is not guaranteed, even with `@Order`. It depends on where the `@Component` class is in the package hierarchy.

EDIT: Also, another wrinkle is that I need the property in the **constructor** of `MyCustomRepository`.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Perhaps create a [custom repositoryFactoryBeanClass](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html#repositoryFactoryBeanClass()) that provides a custom FactoryBean that knows how to deal with `MyCustomRepository`'s constructor.

Comment: why not create `Configuration` class and create bean using `@Bean` ?

Comment: @RyuzakiL huh? it IS a configuration class and the properties ARE a bean. The issue is getting them over to MyCustomRepository.

Comment: @AndrewS I think this might just work. It's DEFINITELY ALOT messier then the static context holder class approach, but it does decouple it from the application -- somewhat. Now the developer will have to specify both the repositoryBaseClass and repositoryFactoryBeanClass FQNs which is another messy part. Although with the static holder, they just had to specify repositoryBaseClass.